# binary search tree segmentation fault in c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

I implemented this function to check if a tree is a binary search tree but it keeps throwing a segfault error

```
  bool checkBST(Node* root) {
   if(root == nullptr){
       return true;
   }
   else{
       if(root->data <= root->left->data){
           return false;
       }
       else if(root->data >= root->right->data){
           return false; 
       }
   }
   return true&&checkBST(root->left)&&checkBST(root->right);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
  root->left->data
```

how do you know that

```
  root->left
```

is not null? If it is you will invoke undefined behaviour when you try to access the `data` member, which may exhibit itself via a seg fault.

Comment: thanks it worked. i don't know how I didn't see that.